# How to make datagridview public

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `dataGridView` (`DataGridViewLAS`) on a form (`FrmImport`) and another `dataGridView` (`dataGridViewPorosity`) on a second form (`FrmPorosity`).

I want to copy 2 columns of `DataGridViewLAS` to `dataGridViewPorosity`, but I get an error:

> FrmPorosity.dataGridViewPorosity is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Code:

```
FrmPorosity.dataGridViewPorosity.Rows.Clear();

if (DataGridViewLAS.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewLAS.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (DataGridViewLAS.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            FrmPorosity.dataGridViewPorosity.Rows.Add();
            FrmPorosity.dataGridViewPorosity.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = DataGridViewLAS.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            FrmPorosity.dataGridViewPorosity.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = DataGridViewLAS.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Select the control at design time. In properties window, set the `Modifiers` property to `Public`.

Answer (score 1):

As these two grids are in different forms. Try to save the first grid data in local variable and then assign that to second grid. Your local variable access specifier must not be private.

```
Var a = DataGridViewLAS.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

DataGridViewLAS.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() = a.ToString();
```

Comment: What’s with all the `ToString()`s? Even on the left side of an assignment?